# Divisibility of $987x^n − F_nx^{16} + F_{n−16}$

Tags: polynomials, divisibility, fibonacci-numbers

> If $F_n$ is $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number, and polynomials $P_n(x)$ are
>   defined as $987x^n − F_nx^{16} + F_{n−16}$, prove that for all $n ≥ 1$, $P_n(x)$ is divisible by $x^2−x−1$.

This is from a contest prep class. The hint was to use induction, but it looks to me it is not really the best path.

Case $n=17$, from Wolfram: *(amazing fact is that the second factor cannot be factored further, even though its degree is 15!)*

[image]

Comment: [I think](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+987x^17-1597x^16%2B1) it should be $987x^n − F_nx^{16} \color{red}+ F_{n−16}$

Comment: @barto Hm, thanks, I doublechecked, and it says -, not +. But maybe there was prior mistake. For now, I think I wrote it correctly.

Comment: Ok, it seems it is really +, right? I will correct it than. @barto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note $\let\phi\varphi$if $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$ and $\psi=-\phi^{-1}$ are the roots of $x^2-x-1$, then $F_n=\frac1{\sqrt5}(\phi^n-\psi^n)$ (also for negative $n$).
Observe $P_n(\phi)=F_{16}\phi^n-F_n\phi^{16}+F_{n-16}=\frac1{\sqrt5}((\color{red}{\phi^{16}}-\color{green}{\psi^{16}})\phi^n-(\color{red}{\phi^n}-\color{blue}{\psi^n})\phi^{16}+(\color{green}{\phi^{n-16}}-\color{blue}{\psi^{n-16}}))=0$.
Therefore the conjugate of $\phi$ in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt5]$, $\psi=-\phi^{-1}=\frac{1-\sqrt5}2$ also satisfies $P_n(\psi)=0$. (You could verify this by hand, but I'm too lazy to do that.)
Hence $x^2-x-1=(x-\phi)(x-\psi)$ is a divisor of $P_n(x)$.

Comment: Note I answered the question for $P_n(x)=F_{16}x^n-F_nx^{16}\color{red}+F_{n-16}$.

Comment: I checked the division for the first three directly, + is correct.

Comment: But check the case n=15... please. @Joffan

Comment: n=15 works with $F_{-1}=1$, but values of n below that don't really work at all. I took n=17 as the initial case, but n=16 works trivially.

Comment: @Joffan i think it should be sign(n-16).

Comment: @Joffan, I think you are right, below 16 nothing works. I will correct the question. this also means that somewhere in the proof there is an implicit condition n>=16.

Comment: Everything works fine below 16. Try [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+987x%5E%2814%29-fibonacci%2814%29x%5E16%2Bfibonacci%2814-16%29&x=0&y=0). The proof still applies.

Comment: Yes, barto is right, I slipped up on the sign of the $x^{16}$ term.

Comment: OK, I am putting back condition n>0 instead of n>=16.

Comment: OK, I am putting back condition n>=1 instead of n>=16.

Answer (score 2):

$P_n(x)$ satisfies the following recursion:

$$P_n(x) =  (1+x)P_{n-1}(x) + (1-x)P_{n-2}(x) - xP_{n-3}(x)$$

Hence by induction it is enough to check that $(x^2-x-1)$ divides it for $n =1,2,3$ which you can verify easily enough.

Comment: I think the correct base would be $n=16,17,18$. It looks there is a problem with $F_{-k}$.

Comment: If you think this could start form 1,2,3, I would appreciate if you explain.

Comment: Sorry, from other comments, it looks cases n<16 are OK too. So base 1,2,3 is fine!

Comment: How did you come to the recurrence relation? :)

Comment: I expanded $(y-x)*(y^2-y-1)$.

Comment: In particular if $y$ is the "shift the index of the sequence by one" operator on the space of sequences of polynomials, then $(y^2-y-1)$ annihilates the Fibonacci terms and $(y-x)$ annihilates the $x^n$ term.